# realm.syncSession.downloadAllServerChanges() is not dowloading the changes on suspend method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, realm-mobile-platform

VerifyPaidStatus is used verify the payment status of a user identified by their id. The function is using a while loop to continuously check the payment status until it is approved. Within the loop, the function is downloading all server changes using `realm.syncSession.downloadAllServerChanges()`, which is a method from the Realm database that syncs data between the local Realm database and a remote server.

However, the data is not being downloaded real-time. I can see the data updated on mongo, but not on the app.

How is this possible?

```
suspend fun verifyPaidStatus(id: String): Boolean
    {
        var out = false
        while(!out)
        {
            realm.syncSession.downloadAllServerChanges()

            realm.write {
                val status =
                    realm.query<PaidStatus>("paidStatusId = $0", id).first().find()
                if (status != null) {
                    findLatest(status)!!.also {
                        if(it.paidStatusId == id && it.message == "Approved") {
                            out = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!out)
                delay(1000)
        }
        return out
    }
```

I call the method using:

```
 val job = withTimeoutOrNull(10000)
 {
     verifyPaidStatus(invoiceId + restaurantMID)
 }

 if(job == null)
    somethingWrong = true
```

Is there any other way to get the latest changes from the server? I just want to check if a value has been added to the database, the value is added on the db server via an Atlas function. I need to check in code if that data has been uploaded to the server successfully.

Comment: Realm is an event driven database which does not generally require any kind of polling, as indicated by the `where` loop in the question. What should happen is the code should be observing the `paidStatusId` and when it updates via an event, take action. There could be many things preventing the code from working as is so additional troubleshooting would help clarify the question. I would suggest changing the approach entirely though - see [react to changes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/react-to-changes/)

Comment: this looks like a big change on the code, dont we have an easier way?
I just to check real time if the value is changed to approved, as simple as that

Comment: Polling is so 1980's! We've come a long way and event driven code is tighter, faster, and won't burn up cpu cycles nor tie up the UI. But, maybe your use case requires it - however without a LOT more info, any answer would only be a guess.

Comment: I just want to check if a value has been added to the database, the value is added on the db server via an Atlas function. I need to check in code if that data has been uploaded to the server successfully.

Comment: The realm documentation specifically states that `downloadAllServerChanges` **This will involve network access, so calling this method should only be done from a non-UI thread**. Secondly, it's not clear why a query is being performed within a `write` block. You're also not handling the returned value from [downloadAllServerChanges](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-sync/-realm%20-kotlin%20-s-d-k%20-%20-sync/io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.sync/-sync-session/download-all-server-changes.html) nor specified a time out. I still think this is the wrong approach.